# How to solve ClassCastException for same class in Jboss EAP 6.5

Tags: jboss, derby

I have created and deployed one war for my application.

I wanted to use derby for integration testing so I created one module in Jboss.

At run time I am getting `ClassCastException` for same class, since the class is getting loaded twice: first from war, then from my module's jar.

To elaborate, my war, say `application.war` contains `myderby.jar` and under my module i have added `myderby.jar` .My class, say `Custom.java`, is present in `myderby.jar`.

Comment: why have you added myderby.jar as a module if it is part of the war?

Comment: I have added because derby module throws class not found exception if I do not add myderby.jar as a module.

Comment: try adding this module as a global module.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me :)

Comment: Sure please go ahead

Comment: What are the other options other than creating global module we can have? If I create global module then i need to manually copy jar to the global modules folder in jboss. Can JBoss pick up the required jar which are already present in war deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a jar to be accessible to multiple WARs, JARs, or an EAR and a WAR/JAR - or in fact any such combination, you can include it as a global module. [Here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Add_a_module_to_all_deployments.html)'s how it can be done.

[This](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7) might also help.

Comment: What are the other options other than creating global module we can have? If I create global module then i need to manually copy jar to the global modules folder in jboss. Can JBoss pick up the required jar which are already present in war deployed?

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested I followed the following link 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Add_a_module_to_all_deployments.html  and it worked for me.